# Subtract pd Series With Non-Matching Indexers in One Level

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to subtract two pd.Series that are MultiIndexed with the same levels, partially match in level values:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Subject':['S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3'],
                  'Movie':['mov1', 'mov1', 'mov2', 'mov2', 'mov1', 'mov1', 'mov2', 'mov2', 'mov1', 'mov1', 'mov2', 'mov2', 'mov3', 'mov3'],
                  'TimeStamp':['Start', 'End', 'Start', 'End', 'Start', 'End', 'Start', 'End', 'Start', 'End', 'Start', 'End', 'Start', 'End'],
                  'Distance': np.random.rand(14)*100}).set_index(['Subject', 'Movie', 'TimeStamp'])['Distance']
b = pd.DataFrame({'Subject':['S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3'],
                  'Movie':['mov1', 'mov1', 'mov2', 'mov2', 'mov2', 'mov1', 'mov1', 'mov2', 'mov2', 'mov1', 'mov1', 'mov1', 'mov2', 'mov2', 'mov2'],
                  'TimeStamp':['Start', 'End', 'Start', 'Mid', 'End', 'Start', 'End', 'Start', 'End', 'Start', 'Mid', 'End','Start', 'Mid', 'End'],
                  'Distance': np.random.rand(15)*100}).set_index(['Subject', 'Movie', 'TimeStamp'])['Distance']
```

Note `b` has a value `Mid` in level `TimeStamp` that doesn't exist in `a`; and on the other hand `a` has value `mov3` in level `Movie` that doesn't exist in `b`.

I'm trying to subtract `b.subtract(a, level=['Subject', 'Movie', 'TimeStamp'])`, but keep failing due to `TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous`.
A possible solution would be to create a copy of both Series and fill the missing values with `0`:

```
index_in_a_not_in_b = set(a.index) - set(b.index)
index_in_b_not_in_a = set(b.index) - set(a.index)
a = a.append(pd.Series([0 for item in index_in_b_not_in_a], index=index_in_b_not_in_a)).sort_index()
b = b.append(pd.Series([0 for item in index_in_a_not_in_b], index=index_in_a_not_in_b)).sort_index()
b.subtract(a, level=['Subject', 'Movie', 'TimeStamp'])

>> out:
Subject  Movie  TimeStamp
S1       mov1   End          27.127491
                Start        18.366840
         mov2   End          13.320173
                Mid          72.190967
                Start        14.303218
S2       mov1   End           0.892581
                Start        11.854033
         mov2   End         -36.461281
                Start        91.406533
S3       mov1   End         -62.710614
                Mid          96.432693
                Start       -35.638531
         mov2   End         -91.539902
                Mid          25.313664
                Start        21.362349
         mov3   End         -79.483691
                Start        -3.146545
dtype: float64
```

This does return the required Series, but will take too long on a large dataset and is not very 'pretty'.

I was wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: Perhaps re-run your example with a specified seed, something like `np.random.seed(42)` otherwise it's really ambiguous to compare. Also not sure why not just `b.subtract(a, fill_value=0)`? You want to align on the entire index, which is the default. The `level` argument is if you only want to use one of those levels.

Comment: @ALollz, The values of the result don't really matter, the point is the result has all index levels that are expected (union of `a.index`, `b.index`). As for `b.subtract(a, fill_value=0)` - it returns `NaN` for all rows.